# Fast way of deleting non-empty Google bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is this my only option or is there a faster way?

```
# Delete contents in bucket (takes a long time on large bucket)
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/*

# Remove bucket
gsutil rb gs://my-bucket/
```

Comment: I want to know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Buckets are required to be empty before they're deleted.  So before you can delete a bucket, you have to delete all of the objects it contains.

You can do this with `gsutil rm -r` ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm)). Just don't pass the `*` wildcard and it will delete the bucket itself after it has deleted all of the objects.

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket
```

Google Cloud Storage bucket deletes can't succeed until the bucket listing returns 0 objects.  If objects remain, you can get a Bucket Not Empty error (or in the UI's case 'Bucket Not Ready') when trying to delete the bucket.

`gsutil` has built-in retry logic to delete both buckets and objects.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as the correct one, but I really feel that there should be a more instant way of deleting a bucket and all its contents. Right now, there's no way avoiding rolling through everything inside a bucket and deleting all objects one by one prior to deleting the bucket itself.

Answer (score 34):

Another option is to enable [Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) on the bucket. You could specify an `Age` of 0 days and then wait a couple days. All of your objects should be deleted.

Comment: Nice suggestion.  Seems to have worked, and faster than waiting for gsutil since I had millions of files.

Comment: I second this! I had 211TB in a bucket I needed deleted, the recursive rm was taking multiple days and I hadn't made a dent. This did the trick really quickly.

Comment: `echo '{"rule":[{"action":{"type":"Delete"},"condition":{"age":0}}]}' > tmp.json; 
gsutil lifecycle set tmp.json gs://MY-BUCKET`

Comment: gsutil lifecycle set <(echo '{"rule":[{"action":{"type":"Delete"},"condition":{"age":0}}]}') gs://MY-BUCKET

Comment: The lifecycle mgmt method is great to get all the objects deleted automatically. After a while, to complete the task, you still want to delete the (then empty) bucket. You can do this with `gsutil rb gs://<bucket>` which will **fail fast** as long as the bucket is not yet empty. Docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rb

Answer (score 9):

Using Python client, you can force a delete within your script by using:

```
bucket.delete(force=True)
```

Try out a similar thing in your current language.

[Github thread that discusses this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1100)

Comment: It seems that the `force` parameter has been removed, and is not available any more. When deleting a bucket from a Google App Engine application, the work-around is to set the lifecycle object as explained, and to schedule a task later on to actually delete the bucket once all objects have been deleted thanks to the lifecycle rule operation. Not very satisfactory…

Answer (score 7):

This deserves to be summarized and pointed out.

Deleting with gsutil rm is slow if you have LOTS (terabytes) of data

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket
```

However, you can specify the expiration for the bucket and let the GCS do the work for you. Create a `fast-delete.json` policy:

```
{
   "rule":[
      {
         "action":{
            "type":"Delete"
         },
         "condition":{
            "age":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

then apply

```
gsutil lifecycle set fast-delete.json gs://MY-BUCKET
```

Thanks, @jterrace and  @Janosch

Answer (score 6):

Use this to set an appropriate lifecycle rule. e.g. wait for a day.

```
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/lifecycle
```

**Example** *(Read carefully before copy paste)*

```
gsutil lifecycle set [LIFECYCLE_CONFIG_FILE] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

**Example** *(Read carefully before copy paste)*

```
{
  "rule":
  [
    {
      "action": {"type": "Delete"},
      "condition": {"age": 1}
    }
  ]
}
```

Then delete the bucket.

> This will delete the data **asynchronously**, so you don't have to keep
>   some background job running on your end.

Answer (score 5):

I benchmarked deletes using three techniques:

- Storage Transfer Service: 1200 - 1500 / sec
- `gcloud storage rm`: 520 / sec
- `gsutil -m rm`: 240 / sec

The big winner is the **Storage Transfer Service**.  To delete files with it you need a source bucket (or folder in a bucket) that is empty, and then you copy that to a destination bucket (or folder in that bucket) that you want to be empty.

If using the GUI select this bullet in the advanced transfer options dialog:
[image: Advanced Transfer Options]

You can also create and run the job from the CLI.  This example assumes you have access to `gs://bucket1/empty/` (which has no objects in it) and you want to delete all objects from `gs://bucket2/`:

```
gcloud transfer jobs create \
gs://bucket1/empty/ gs://bucket2/ \
--delete-from=destination-if-unique \
--project my-project
```

If you want your deletes to happen even faster you'll need to create multiple transfer jobs and have them target different sections of the bucket.  Because it has to do a bucket listing to find the files to delete you'd want to make the destination paths non-overlapping (e.g. gs://bucket2/folder1/ and gs://bucket2/folder2/, etc).  Each job will process in parallel at speed getting the job done in less total time.

Usually I like this better than using Object Lifecycle Management (OLM) because it starts right away (no waiting up to 24 hours for policy evaluation) but there may be times when OLM is the way to go.

Comment: This answer (which is similar to your other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73806538/199475)) works very well for me.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter one liner for the lifecycle change:

```
gsutil lifecycle set <(echo '{"rule":[{"action":{"type":"Delete"},"condition":{"age":0}}]}') gs://MY-BUCKET
```

I've also had good luck creating an empty bucket then starting a transfer to the bucket I want to empty out. Our largest bucket took about an hour to empty this way; the lifecycle method seems to take at least a day.

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: Creating an empty bucket and copy that to the target worked best here! Much faster than gsutil! Transfer Option "Delete files from destination if they’re not also at source" is key here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bucket from Developers Console. It will ask for confirmation before deleting a non empty bucket. It works like a charm ;)

Comment: This works well for most buckets, but it just silently fails to delete buckets with a very large number of objects.

Comment: @KelseyFrancis that's the exact situation I've run into as well. Just fails to delete the bucket if it has a large number of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both ways (expiration time and gsutil command direct to bucket root), but I could not wait to the expiration time to propagate.

The gsutil rm was deleting 200 files per second, so I did this:

Open several terminal and executed the gsutil rm using different "folder" names with *

ie:

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/a*
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/b*
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/c*
```

In this example, the command is able to delete 600 files per second.
So you just need to open more terminals and find the patterns to delete more files.
If one wildcard is huge, you can detail, like this

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/b1*
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/b2*
gsutil -m rm -r gs://my-bucket/b3*
```