# Deleting a large folder from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a folder in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, which has millions of files that I need to remove.

What is an efficient way to delete this large folder of files, without having to delete the entire bucket?

I've tried using the `gsutil rm` command, but it seems like it will take a long time to finish deleting all files.

Furthermore, I also read about **Object Lifecycle Management** policies, but I read that they apply to the entire bucket, as opposed to any specific folder.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gsutil rm` will be fastest.  Your only alternative is to write code to list and delete each one, which is what gsutil is going to do for you.

Comment: One suggestion to speed this up. Launch a Compute Engine instance in the same region and run the `gcloud rm` command in the GCE instance. The packets size for the REST APIs calls for deleting objects is small. The low latencies and high bandwidth within the same region will make a big difference in total command execution time.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm doing right now, thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: It seems that gsutil rm isn't now recommended, as noted in Best practices at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#deleting "If you want to bulk delete a hundred thousand or more objects, avoid using gsutil, as the process takes a long time to complete. Instead, use ... Cloud Console ... or ... Object Lifecycle Management". Any idea about REST API, for instance, which would do the job instead of clicking in Cloud Console?

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Storage Transfer Service**, my experience is it can delete 1-1.5k objects per second.

Delete files by copying from a source bucket (or folder in a bucket) that is empty, to a destination bucket or folder that you want to be empty and use the ***delete files at destination that aren't at the source*** option.

If using the GUI select this bullet in the advanced transfer options dialog:
[image: Advanced Transfer Options]

You can also create and run the job from the CLI.  This example assumes you have access to `gs://bucket1/empty/` (which has no objects in it) and you want to delete all objects from `gs://bucket2/folder1/`:

```
gcloud transfer jobs create \
gs://bucket1/empty/ gs://bucket2/folder1/ \
--delete-from=destination-if-unique \
--project my-project
```

If you want your deletes to happen even faster you'll need to create multiple transfer jobs and have them target different sections of the bucket.  Because it has to do a bucket listing to find the files to delete you'd want to make the destination paths non-overlapping (e.g. gs://bucket2/folder1/ and gs://bucket2/folder2/, etc).  Each job will process in parallel at speed getting the job done in less total time.