# What is the command line to delete firebase storage folder or file?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have been searching in vain for quite some time how to delete a Firebase storage (i.e. not Firestore or Real-Time Database).

For Firestore it is possible to simply use `firebase firestore delete [path]`. What is the equivalent for Firebase Storage assuming want to delete an `/images` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase CLI does not have any options for working with Cloud Storage.  You will have to use the [gsutil CLI](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) instead.  It has an [rm command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm) for this.

See also: [Deleting a large folder from Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859506/deleting-a-large-folder-from-google-cloud-storage)